# google sheet : query to return row number rather than the value itself

Tags: google-sheets

I have this formula :

```
=filter(A10:A, R10:R=S10:S)
```

It will extract all data from column A with condition where the value of column R and S are equal. It works fine but i want it to output the row number rather than the value in column A.

How can i do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

`=FILTER(ROW(A10:A), R10:R=S10:S)`